# Excel where each cell contains both letters and numbers sum numbers based on letters

Tags: microsoft-excel

So the idea is to sum the area (k, t or w) the person worked in while we swap the staff round areas on a daily basis to analyse performance in the areas.

[image]

```
employee name,contracted hours,day1,day2
Anne,7.5,k07.5,w05.0
Bob,7.5,t07.5,k07.5
Claire,7.5,w07.5,t07.5
Dave,6.0,k07.5,w07.5
Ellen,6.0,t07.5,k07.5
Fred,6.0,w06.0,t07.5
```

And so on for each day.

I want to be able to sum each area k, t and w at the bottom of each day for all employees and at the end of each row for each employee.

I could split the cells, but it would be better (as in a lot faster) if I didn't have to.

Comment: Could you give an example? Not really sure what you mean

Comment: Please improve your explanation and include an example. We can't help you if the information is incomplete.

Comment: still not really clear:(. Please also add desired output. Especially I don't understand "bottom of each day". You can upload your screenshot to e.g. imgur and include the link in your question, then somebody with enough reputation will insert it for you.

Comment: Mike is combining the area a contractor worked in with the actual hours they worked in that area. He wants row total and column totals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand you want to sum all K's together and so on with T's and W's e.g. Try the following.

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF(LEFT(C2:C7,1)="K",MID(C2:C7,2,LEN(C2:C7)),0)*1)}
```

This is an array formula so you should eventually enter CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER key in the formula bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had missed some elements out which were preventing me from getting a result. Much appreciated!